# Shallow, Nested, Namespaced classes in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following setup:

```rb
# routes.rb

namespace :forum do
  resources :sections, shallow: true do
    resources :threads, shallow: true do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
end
```

with the expected models/etc. Rails routes looks like:
[image: Picture of rails routes]
When I try to use

```rb
# /app/views/forum/threads/new.html.haml
# @forum_section / @forum_thread correctly set in controller

= simple_form_for [@forum_section, @forum_thread] do |f|
  # some form content here
```

I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `forum_section_forum_threads_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f6af7623b80>:0x00007f6af49780b8>
Did you mean?  forum_section_threads_path):
```

Well - yes, of course I meant that.

But there has got to be a better way than:

```rb
= simple_form_for [@forum_section, @forum_thread], url: forum_section_threads_path(@forum_section)
```

Yuck. A violation of DRY in one line.

I **know** I must be missing something stupid here - help me out?

Answer (score 1):

#### Non-namespaced solution

Try

```
= simple_form_for [:thread, @forum_section, @forum_thread] do |f|
  # some form content here
```

[Source](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)

This is assuming `@forum_section` is a persisted instance of the `Section` class and `@forum_thread` is a new instance of the `Thread` class.

Normally, if your routes have resources like `:sections` and `:threads`, your models would be called `Section` and `Thread`. And for convention, your instance variables would also be called `@section` and `@thread`, but their name isn't so important. If your setup is different than this, it can make it hard for Rails to guess which URL you're trying to generate.

#### Namespaced solution

If you want to keep the models under the same namespace, like `Forum::Section` and `Forum::Thread`, you have to also change the default naming for the path helpers

```
namespace :forum do
  resources :sections, shallow: true, as: :forum_sections do
    resources :threads, shallow: true, as: :forum_threads do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
end
```

[Source](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers)

Comment: ```simple_form_for [:thread, @forum_section, @forum_thread]``` generates ```ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `thread_forum_section_forum_threads_path'``` - adding ```:thread``` simply specifies the method name, and is used for adding things like ```:edit``` to a url.

Comment: Re: naming - the names of the instance variables come directly from the generator - but rails doesn't care specifically what you call them - it infers the url from the class name of the objects in those variables. Changing to ```@section``` and ```@thread``` had no effect; it still tried to call ```forum_section_forum_threads_path```. This has to do with namespacing, since without it, the generated url method calls work fine (but code becomes entirely unmanageable in large projects without namespacing).

Comment: Have you tried moving the `Section` and `Thread` models out of the `Forum` namespace? I've used namespaces before, and I only had to move the controller and views under a namespace. But my models did not have to be under the same namespace.

Comment: While that would work, I think the solution is probably more ugly than specifying the url manually - while it doesn't violate DRY, it does limit maintainability of the models (no more nice namespacing), and destroys the convention of having the MVC structures mirrored. I want to be able to use namespacing everywhere, not just in some parts of the MVC structure.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#controller
@forum_thread = Thread.new

#view
= simple_form_for [:forum, @forum_section, @forum_thread]
```

The form action will be POST /sections/:id/threads

Comment: The problem here is the namespacing; this works just fine without, but with, it breaks. The issue here is in the controller:

```@forum_thread = Forum::Thread.new```

That namespacing destroys the nice url_for method that's used to make the url.